# Can I use either with three+ items in negative sentences, as in the example I give?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct:

> I'm not either creative, motivated, or honest?

I'm debating it with an English teacher, and I've sent them several sources that prove my point, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: You are saying that **either** allows for 3 items. It does not. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "either" be used for more than two items?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63428/can-either-be-used-for-more-than-two-items) Also [either or with more than two alternatives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193006/either-or-with-more-than-two-alternatives) and [how to use either with more than three options with the word based on](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197258/how-to-use-either-with-more-than-three-options-with-the-word-based-on), among others.

Comment: The academics will tell you it is not correct.  In practice, you will frequently encounter  this usage.  You'd probably be *understood* by most speakers, but you'd probably fail a test.

Comment: Can you show us the sources you've been referring to that prove your point?
(Also, "not either" is wrong. Use "neither" instead.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different question than the others I've seen, but has overlap. You're actually asking several different questions here I think:

### How Many Options

The word "either" presents a list of options to choose from and indicates that only one of options can be selected. In formal writing or speech, this list should be exactly 2 options, but informally, it can have 2 or more. (Both you and your teacher are right.)

### Either vs Neither

However, your example sentence is incorrect. When the word "either" is made negative, it becomes "neither" instead, and the word "nor" takes the place of "or" in the list. So you could say "I am neither creative nor honest."

The word neither is nearly always used in formal usage today, which means that the sentence "I am neither creative, motivated, nor honest" sounds very strange. Remember, in formal English, neither can only be 2.

### And vs Or

Interestingly, when "either" is used, it means that one item out of the list is or will be selected.

For example, "I am either creative, motivated, or honest" means that you are one of those, but not all three. To pick one or more from the list, leave off the word either and just say "I am creative, motivated, or honest." and to pick all three, say "I am creative, motivated, and honest."

On the other hand, "neither" works differently. Neither means that *none* of the things in the list are selected. "I am neither creative nor motivated" means that I am not creative and I am not motivated.